# Check registered phone number on Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

in telethon library python is there a way for me to know if a certain phone number is registered or not

I tried using `InputPhoneContact` to check if `telethon.tl.types.User` is present if it is present it is registered and if it is not present it is not registered, but some registered accounts it still doesn't appear, Is there a better way?

Comment: https://github.com/bellingcat/telegram-phone-number-checker/blob/main/telegram-phone-validation.py